# Making countdown bar with pv

Tags: bash, sleep, pv

Following this 2013 question, on [displaying a countdown in a terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/611538/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-countdown-or-stopwatch-timer-in-a-terminal), I would like to improve the answer a bit using `pv` to show a progression bar.

Here is my current script.

```
function countdown {
   date1=$((`date +%s` + $1));
   while [ "$date1" -ge `date +%s` ]; do
     echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date1 - `date +%s`)) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
     sleep 0.1
   done
}

# 7 minutes countdown
countdown $((7*60))
```

How do I improve this with `pv`? It looks like it tracks progress measuring data written. In my case I just need to wait and I don't have indicators to measure.

Maybe there are best alternatives as of 2018?

Thanks.

Comment: `pv` is a wrong tool for the purpose, see the answer below.

Comment: Do you know other tools to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it this way with `pv`, writing one Byte of character every second.

```
secs=$((7 * 60))
while [ $secs -gt 0 ]
do 
  echo -n "."
  sleep 1
  : $((secs--))
done | pv -s $secs > /dev/null
```

`echo -n` is for

```
  -n     do not output the trailing newline
```

`pv -s` is for

```
  -s, --size SIZE          set estimated data size to SIZE bytes
```

`sleep 1; : $((secs--))` to decrement the value of `$secs` every  1 second

Comment: Start with 1MB file, divide it by number of secs to obtain several chunks, then write the file concatenate the file back ?

Comment: Better that way. But still, this is like using a hammer to pin a screw. `secs=10;
while [ "$secs" -gt 0 ];
do 
  echo -n ".";
  sleep 1;
  secs=$((secs-1));
done | pv -s "$secs" > /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot improve this with `pv`. `pv` stands for Pipe View, and it tracks the progress of a data flow. Knowing the size and measuring the quantity of data passingh through it, it can give you an estimate of remaining time.
If you just need a timer countdown, `pv` is useless.

You already have something written that can be embellished. Other scripts for your need exists in the web: http://handybashscripts.blogspot.com/2012/01/simple-timer-with-progress-bar.html

Comment: But can I artificially build a file that takes exactly 7 min to process?

Comment: That would be overkill and innacurate. The file could take too much storage space and the timing will depend on the variable speed of the underlying file system. Probably you could manage to do something in that way, but it won't be accurate and, for sure, it won't be an improvement.

Comment: Or `curl` a webservice that timeouts after exactly 7 minutes ?

Comment: Are you really considering an improvement having to implement a webservice that times out after 7 minutes against a simple `sleep`???

Comment: I think I might have an answer, please have a look.

Comment: There is one webservice that does exactly that ah ah
https://lifehacker.com/5610036/use-a-simple-web-app-as-a-live-countdown-timer
My initial problem was to wait to show a webpage. I must wait 7 min for the infrastructure to bootstrap. I can basically do a command line curl pv with this or do an HTML redirect in JavaScript after 7 min.